# How to load a GBA emulator save state on a new phone on My Boy!

Tags: emulation, my-boy

I got a new phone and now my emulator can't find, let alone read, the st0, st1, etc. save states I had. I synced my save states to Google drive and redownloaded them onto my new phone in the same file path as my old phone but My Boy still doesnt show any file when I search in the same path.

Comment: Do you have a way to clarify if the versions of My Boy! are the same between your old phone and new? If your old phone was old enough, the versions may be different, and saves may not be compatible, but that's just speculation.

Comment: I would try doing new save states, and looking at where they go and get saved. Then put your same files there.